# Repeated column in mapping for entity: Shipper column: SHIPPER_ID (should be mapped with insert="false"

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have been going around in circles with this error and not sure why I am getting this.

Here is the mapping of Shipper class

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="SALONBOOKS",name="SHIPPER")
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="SHIPPER_ID"))
public class Shipper extends SalonObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ShipperType name;//ShipperType.WALKIN;

    @Column(name="SHIPPER_NAME")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public ShipperType getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(ShipperType name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override   
    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Here is Order class which references Shipper

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="SALONBOOKS",name="ORDER")
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="ORDER_ID"))
public class Order extends SalonObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BigDecimal total= new BigDecimal(0.0);
    private int numOfItems=0;
    private BigDecimal tax= new BigDecimal(0.0);;
    private String currency="USD";
    private BigDecimal subTotal= new BigDecimal(0.0);
    private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;
    private Shipper shipper;
    private OrderStatusType status;
    private Appointment appointment ;
    private Person person;

    @Column(name="TOTAL")
    public BigDecimal getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(BigDecimal total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    @Column(name="NUM_OF_ITEMS")
    public int getNumOfItems() {
        return numOfItems;
    }
    public void setNumOfItems(int numOfItems) {
        this.numOfItems = numOfItems;
    }
    @Column(name="TAX")
    public BigDecimal getTax() {
        return tax;
    }
    public void setTax(BigDecimal tax) {
        this.tax = tax;
    }
    @Column(name="CURRENCY")
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    @Column(name="SUBTOTAL")
    public BigDecimal getSubTotal() {
        return subTotal;
    }
    public void setSubTotal(BigDecimal subTotal) {
        this.subTotal = subTotal;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PAYMENT_METHOD_ID", insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public PaymentMethod getPaymentMethod() {
        return paymentMethod;
    }
    public void setPaymentMethod(PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SHIPPER_ID", insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public Shipper getShipper() {
        return shipper;
    }
    public void setShipper(Shipper shipVia) {
        this.shipper = shipVia;
    }
    @Column(name="STATUS")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public OrderStatusType getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(OrderStatusType status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="APPOINTMENT_ID", insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public Appointment getAppointment() {
        return appointment;
    }
    public void setAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        this.appointment = appointment;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID", insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }       

    @Override
    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }   
}
```

each of these extends:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class SalonObject implements Entity, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected Long id;
    protected DateTime createDate;
    protected DateTime updateDate;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof SalonObject 
                && obj !=null){
            return ObjectUtils.equals(this.id, ((SalonObject) obj).getId()) ;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Column(name="CREATE_DATE")
    public DateTime getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(DateTime dateTime) {
        this.createDate = dateTime;
    }
    @Column(name="UPDATE_DATE")
    public DateTime getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(DateTime updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }
}
```

The stackTrace is ::

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: salonbooks.model.Shipper column: SHIPPER_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at salonbooks.core.HibernateConfiguration.sessionFactory(HibernateConfiguration.java:109)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing the following method from Shipper and from Order worked to resolve this error

```
@Override   
public Long getId(){
    return id;
}
```

Because you are using property access, by overriding the base method (containing the mapping configuration) you will replace your base method mapping configuration with no config at all.

Using field access wouldn't have caused this issue, but the override would have been useless anyway. The id field should have private access too, so this method wouldn't compile if you change the access modifier.